# Problema con permalink dentro de bucle ACF Post Object

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Llevo unas horas dándole vueltas y no consigo que se generen los enlaces de la función de Wordpress excerpt_more correctamente. Por un lado tengo el filtro:

```
function modify_read_more_link($more) {
   global $post;
   $more = ' <a href="'. get_permalink( ) .'">Continue reading<span</a>';
   return $more;
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'modify_read_more_link');
```

Y por otro el bucle generado según la [documentación de ACF para Post Object](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object) (Display data for multiple post objects):

```
$post_objects = get_field('post_objects');
if( $post_objects ): ?>
   <ul>
   <?php foreach( $post_objects as $post):?>
      <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
      <li>
         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
         <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
      </li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
   </ul>
   <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Al acceder a the_excerpt() no utiliza el permalink adecuado en el Continue reading generado.
Alguna idea? Mil gracias de antemano.

Comment: prueba con `<?php echo get_the_excerpt($post); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

La función `get_permalink()` requiere como parámetro el ID del post del que querés obtener el permalink. Probá de esta manera:

```
$more = ' <a href="'. get_permalink( $post->ID ) .'">Continue reading<span</a>';
```

Comment: Gracias Lagg3r, pero el enlace que no responde como debería no es ese. De hecho ese responde al bucle, pero la función que no genera el link correcto es el que se crea con the_excerpt(). El de read_more.
Por lo que entiendo, la función the_excerpt() recibe el post_ID correcto y genera el contenido de excerpt. Pero a la hora de ejecutar la funciónque genera el enlace read_more, no envía el ID del post correcto